# First SSHed to server when VPN connected, now can't SSH without VPN

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, vpn

When I first SSHed (RSA passwordless, there's no password) to a server that I'd just set up (`ssh root@X.X.X.X`) on DigitalOcean, I forgot that my VPN was connected.  If I'd remembered, I would have switched it off.

However, now when I try to connect to the server without the VPN being connected, I get connection refused:

```
ssh: connect to host X.X.X.X port 22: Connection refused
```

Using `netstat -rn` this line only appears when connected to the VPN:

```
X.X.X.X      Y.Y.Y.Y      UGHS            2      409     en0
```

Where `Y.Y.Y.Y` is the local router gateway.

I want to have the ability to SSH regardless of whether the VPN is connected or not.  Can anyone help me achieve this?

Or would I be better trashing the server on DigitalOcean and starting again, without the VPN connected?

I'm using OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Seems unlikely that it has anything to do with _originally_having the VPN up, but rather that the configuration of the virtual machine you have doesn't allow ssh in from the outside.  Unless you have encoded the IP address of the server into your ~/.ssh/config or something.  You are using the proper external IP address of your server, I assume.

Comment: Yes, it's the proper external IP and I haven't put it in any config files.  I have other servers with DigitalOcean which are all fine - the only difference with this one is that I had the VPN connected when I set it up.  Thanks for your thoughts.